# Which Image size is used on detection? .cfg file vs cv2.dnn.blobFromImage()

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo

I'm using https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet

I have my custom yolov3-tiny model and I trained it with the size of 416 * 416 in .cfg file.

```
[net]
# Testing
batch=1
subdivisions=1
width=416
height=416
channels=3
```

I understand that training starts after converting training images of various sizes to 416 * 416.

And I understand that this command changes input image size to 416 * 416 as in .cfg file and detects objects in  ~.jpg

```
./darknet detect  ~.cfg  ~.weights  ~.jpg
```

Now I'm using Opencv dnn module on detection.

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("./custom.weights", "./custom.cfg")
.
.
.
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1/255, (416, 416), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
outs = net.forward(getOutputsNames(net))
```

I changed (416, 416) to (608, 608) in blobFromImage() and it still works fine on detecting objects. But what is the image size actually used on the network? Is it 608 * 608 or 416 * 416 ? Does size parameters in blobFromImage() take precedence over .cfg file?

Comment: I have the same question my guy :/